# continuous integration with XCode bots and cocoapods

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode5, cocoapods, xcode-bots

I'm having problems with bots occasionally failing when building.
A pre build action is used to install the pods, this works well some times. However when the integration fails it's because of this error:

```
Installing Pods
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
[32mInstalling AFNetworking (1.3.3)[0m
...
2014-03-07 10:40:25.667 xcodebuild[76637:100b] [MT] IDEFileReferenceDebug: [Load] <IDEFileReference, 0x7fa3fe5b0840: group:Pods/Pods.xcodeproj> Failed to load container at path: /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/5bbd629b-a843-42b0-8b52-256db7560be5/source/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj, Error: Error Domain=Xcode3ProjectErrorDomain Code=2 "Project /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/5bbd629b-a843-42b0-8b52-256db7560be5/source/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file." UserInfo=0x7fa3fe7e54b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Project /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/5bbd629b-a843-42b0-8b52-256db7560be5/source/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file.}
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

So my guess is that xcodebuld tries to read the Pods-project before it's done being generated.

Does this sound like a reasonable guess?

And would anyone know how to solve it?

**EDIT**
Pre-action build script looks lie this

```
cd $SRCROOT

export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

if [ -d Pods ]
then
echo "Updating Pods"
pod update
else
echo "Installing Pods"
pod install
```

Comment: Can you show show us pre-build action?

Comment: How your scheme look like? Which XCode version ?

Comment: This CocoaPods issue thread has a few tidbits that may help: https://github.com/CocoaPods/blog.cocoapods.org/issues/21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the xCode server work with cocoapods pretty seamlessly, have a look at my article, it may help you.

http://papaanton.com/setting-up-xcode-6-and-apple-server-4-0-for-continues-integration-with-cocoapods/

I do the clean build every time with Pod install.

It maybe the reason.

Comment: Yes, It's seems to work much better with OS X server 4.0

Comment: Link seems to be broken. Can anyone help with correct link?

Comment: Link broken, Please provice your answer inside SO not linking to other sites so if links get broken the answer don't

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods is really undependable with Xcode bots in general when the pod project is not being tracked by your SVN. I also do not track the pod project and have similar troubles with CocoaPods. If you are looking for a temporary fix, you can go to `/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/5bbd629b-a843-42b0-8b52-256db7560be5/source/`, run pod install from there and remove the pre-build script. Though if you update your Podfile or Podfile.lock, you will have to manually run pod install/pod update on the server again.

Comment: Thanks, but definitely not the solution I'm looking for